# IIS handle static files?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Does IIS handle request that of static file eg:

```
http://localhost:9000/Content/ABC.pdf
```

If it doesnt then can we add some setting so that the .pdf request is also handled by IIS and it passes through URLRewite module.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net only receives requests for aspx, asmx, ashx.

If a file name extension has not been mapped to ASP.NET, ASP.NET will not receive the request.

If you create a custom handler to service a particular file name extension, you must map the extension to ASP.NET in IIS and also register the handler in your application's Web.config file. For more information, see [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

If possible change your url to an ashx file. If not, you can map pdf to be recognized by asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IIS handles static content just fine (it does serve images up, right?).

By default it will bypass any dynamic processing and return the content directly.

If your setup does not automatically handle PDF files correctly, you may simply need to [add the correct mime type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to the configuration.

Comment: it does handle correctly but i have added a URL Rewrite for .pdf file, that is not working.

<rewrite>
    <rules>
     <rule name="Forward to static file server">
      <match url="^.+\.(?:pdf)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:9000/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>

Comment: @shakti - Exactly. IIS _bypasses_ the ASP.NET engine for static files. You can set the mimetype to get processed by ASP.NET if you really need to.